# Android shell terminal using sqlite3

Tags: android, sqlite, terminal, command

When you are doing queries in your android shell terminal with sqlite3,
are there any way to show again the previous query?

UP arrow usually show you the previous commands executed, can we also do it in sqlite3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in my android shell terminal as following:

1. Open cmd.exe, input:

   adb shell
   Sqlite3
2. Do some sql query statement, and use up arrow to show the previous command you run:

   sqlite> insert into my_table values('1', 'Mrhihi');

   insert into my_table values('1', 'Mrhihi');

   sqlite> select * from my_table;

   select * from my_table;

   1|Mrhihi

   sqlite> select * from my_table;

   select * from my_table;

   1|Mrhihi

   sqlite> insert into my_table values('1', 'Mrhihi');

   insert into my_table values('1', 'Mrhihi');

See, the up arrow can be used in Sqlite3.

Comment: Well, I'm using the console in my MAC and every time I press any arrow key this is what I have " ^[[A  " which is annoying me due to I have to copy or I cannot even go back to edit what I'm writing.

Comment: OK, I am working on my Windows. I also met this up arrow issue on my Linux before. Sorry, still not fix your issue.